# Node.js POST login request doesn't return authenticated cookie

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, postman

I am making a private API wrapper (Edit: I don't have the server-side code since I'm making this for another website, sort of like the Instagram-private-API module) with Node.js and currently, I'm working on the authentication part. When I send the POST request from Postman I get an authenticated JSESSIONID cookie in the response eg.

Request:

```
POST /Login.do HTTP/1.1
Host: awebsite.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: x
username=myusername&password=mypassword
```

And the response contains a JSESSIONID, the HTML website content with the logged-in user's information, and a status of 200.

But for some reason when I run the same exact request with Axios (I've tried many alternative modules too) the response HTML I get doesn't contain the user's info, nor does the JSESSIONID cookie return that information when I try it on an alternative endpoint from postman.

Node.js code:

```
...
const data = qs.stringify({
    'username': 'myusername',
    'password': 'mypassword' 
});

const config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://awebsite.com/Login.do',
    headers: { 
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    data
};

axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

I have no idea what the problem may be. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922387/authenticate-via-post-request-in-node-js) had a similar issue to mine, but instead of the response not containing the user data or correct JSESSIONID, the problem resided in the redirect to the user's dashboard.

Comment: Have you logged the POST data in your node route? Does your request correctly contain the body params? Have you tried the example code here? https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosconfig (i.e. not manually setting headers and the body string)?

Comment: @ChrisG I've tried, tried it now just to be sure. It still returns the same response

Comment: Well, do your parameters username & password actually make it to your server (node & express route, I assume)? Are you logging them to the node console?

Comment: @ChrisG Currently I'm just working on this part, and I'm not using routes just simply hard coding

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you can't answer my question I'm going to move on to another question. This is already taking too long for my taste (7 minutes ago I was asking for logged POST params). Can you add the relevant server-side code to the question?

Comment: @ChrisG I don't have the server-side code. I'm making this for another website (kinda like the instagram-private-api module)

Comment: Ok, so the above is node code? I assumed you were trying to log into your own server from the browser. In that case, what does it say in the server's reply? Is it completely empty?

Comment: @ChrisG No it's not it has HTML, but the problem is that the HTML doesn't have the user information it has when the same request is sent from postman

Comment: *Ok, so what does it actually say?* Any indication in the reply of what went wrong?

Comment: @ChrisG No, the site I'm working with is extremely out-dated and all of the validation happens on the client-side. The response code I'm getting is 200, and there are no errors present within the HTML

Answer (score 0):

I had to take a few steps back to just take a look at everything a user does to login. The most important bit here was the initial GET request to the server which renders the login form.

I usually skip over that, but this time I thought about it deeper and looked at the cookies that my browser had before and after the login. I noticed that the session id (which is needed for all future requests) always stayed the same, so I made a function that GET's the website and stores the session id cookie to a variable. After that I was able to authenticate that cookie and get the logged in version of the website with the same code I was using before with an added 'Cookie' header.

The full request function:

```
const data = qs.stringify({ username, password });

const config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://awebiste.com/Login.do',
    headers: {
        Cookie: this.cookie,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    data,
};

const res = await axios(config);
```

The JSESSIONID generator:

```
const { headers } = await axios.get('https://awebiste.com');

const JSESSIONID = headers['set-cookie']
    .find((c) => c.startsWith('JSESSIONID'))
    .split(/(?<=;)/)[0];

return JSESSIONID;
```